# BOOLEAN varibles support for SNMP V2

Tags: snmp, snmpv2c

I need to test some software drivers for SNMP v2 protocol. I am not getting it clear whether this protocol supports BOOL tags or not. I am using this simulator (SNMP Agent simulator (https://ireasoning.com/download.shtml). How do I configure digital tag in this simulator ?

Comment: What do you mean by "BOOL tags"? There are only a few basic data types supported by SNMP, https://www.webnms.com/cagent/help/technology_used/c_snmp_overview.html#datatypes, and no BOOLEAN.

Comment: The closest I can see is TruthValue from RFC 2579 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2579

Comment: We have this object upsAlarmOnBattery from Eaton MIB. But I can not add this via my SCADA driver. https://imgur.com/r7APF18